# Multiple paragraph footnotes in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, footnotes

I have an org-mode document with a footnote:

```
This some text[fn:1]. This is another text[fn:2].

* Footnotes

[fn:1] This is footnote's first line.

This is footnote's second line.

[fn:2] Another footnote
```

Then i resort and renumber footnotes by pressing <kbd>C-u C-c C-x f S</kbd> - `org-footnote-action` which executes `(org-footnote-renumber-fn:N)` and `(org-footnote-normalize 'sort)`. The result is:

```
This some text[fn:1]. This is another text[fn:2].

* Footnotes

[fn:1] This is footnote's first line.

[fn:2] Another footnote
```

The second paragraph of the footnote is lost. This makes multiple paragraph footnotes impossible in org-mode. One semi-solution is to make a separate footnote for every paragraph, but i don't want that.

Is there any possibility to preserve structure in the footnote? What should i do to make org-mode not delete the text in the footnotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [org mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Footnotes.html):

> If you need a paragraph break inside a footnote, use the LaTeX idiom
>   ‘\par’.

It worked for me:

```
This some text[fn:1]. This is another text[fn:2].

* Footnotes

[fn:1] This is footnote's first line.\par
\par
This is footnote's second line.

[fn:2] Another footnote
```

Comment: In order to get a blank line between paragraphs, you can also use: `[fn:1] First line.\\~\\Second line.`

Comment: The documentation linked no longer contains the quoted phrase.  When exporting to HTML, I found that `\par` did not work.  I found that I needed to place `\\` at the end of the first paragraph, followed by a single line consisting only of another `\\`, and then beginning the second paragraph on a new line.

Answer (score 7):

For people visiting through google or who otherwise visit years later (as I did): this is now different. Multiple paragraphs are easily achieved, as footnotes only end after a two consecutive empty lines.

See https://orgmode.org/org.html#Creating-Footnotes :

> It ends at the next footnote definition, headline, or after two consecutive empty lines